# How to check for SQLite database file existence in Xamarin and create a new database file if there were no such a database?

Tags: xamarin

I'm trying to write a method for checking SQLite file existence. I downloaded a Nuget package for SQLite functionalities named System.Data.SQLite.Core.
I wrote this code for the method:

```
 string path = "ReportData.db";

        private void Create_db()
        {
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(path);
                using (var sqlite = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=" + path))
                {
                    sqlite.Open();
                    string sql = "create table temp(date varchar(20),activity varchar(1000))";
                    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, sqlite);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sqlite.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

I don't know where to create my SQLite database file. When I use this method in a button, the application goes into break mode and says:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path
> "/ReportData.db" is denied.'

Please help me.

Comment: to start with, you're using the wrong nuget package.  Xamarin has [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases) on using SQLite that explain how to do this.  The `SQLiteConnection` constructor will create an empty db if one does not exist, and you also use `File.Exists` to check for the db file first if needed

Comment: I studied your provided link. I have a TimePicker control in my project. How can I bind its text (string) into code? What property should be used for binding?

Comment: use the `Time` property

Comment: For example, I used this XAML for TimePicker: `<TimePicker x:Name="Time_Start" HorizontalOptions="Center" Time="{Binding TimeStamp1}" />`

Comment: But when I run my app to save data into db3 file, a runtime error is displayed: `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

Comment: this seems like a completely new issue, so you should post a new question and include the relevant code